# how can I find github issues by close date?

Tags: github

Is there a way to get the GitHub issues that were closed on-or-near a date?   I have a commit in my codebase that does not reference an issue, and I'm wondering if it was done in response to a particular issue.

Ideally, I'd like to say "show me issues that were closed after August 10"

Answer (score 18):

Use `closed:` to search for issues based on date closed. For example, to find issues closed after Aug 10, 2020, do

```
closed:>2020-08-10
```

You can also use a range. For example, to find issues closed in February or March of 2020, do:

```
closed:2020-02-01..2020-03-31
```

On the other hand, using `state:closed updated:>=YYYY-MM-DD` returns all issues that are *currently* closed and have been *updated* anytime on or after a particular date, which is not necessarily the same thing.

See the GitHub doc sections on the ["closed" qualifier](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-when-an-issue-or-pull-request-was-closed) and [working with dates](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-dates).

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at GitHub [Searching issues and pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/)
.

An example would be something like:

`state:closed updated:>=2013-02-01`

with the date format as described in the docs as `updated:YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: should bee add that the format is YYYY-MM-DD, as somes, like me, will think the format could be DD-MM

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a good example for using this to make a range?  My attempt ended in an OR scenario, not desirable...

Comment: I tried using `updated:>2023-10-20` in a GitHub Project Board but GitHub rejected it and told me it _only_ supported `updated:<@today-Nd` or `updated:<@today-Nw` or `updated:<@today-Nm` - whereas `last-updated:5days` works fine - weird